# Not able to clone repository

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When i try to clone the repository the following error pops up. [error when I try to clone the repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YOSR.png). After creating an account in BitBucket I tried to clone the repository. While doing the same in eclipse I encountered a transport error.

It says that the possible reasons for the error are : Incorrect url, no network connection, ssl host could not be verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't clear enough. But I think it's that the http.sslVerify that needs to be set to false. To clone the repository.

Uploaded the image for reference please check.

**Eclipse > Window > Preferences**

*Search for git in the filter.*

**Configuration > Add Entry**.

[Check this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PffYs.png)

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your repo on bitbucket by following the steps below:
while opening the field with the code to clone your repository you can see a dropbox with the value 'SSH'.
1. change this value to 'https'
2. Use this code to clone your repo 'git clone git@bitbucket.org:...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by going to Eclipse > Window > Preferences>General>Network Connection> and setting the connection to manual and adding the url according to the required example. In the https we have to add the Github url with port number. We need to add the id and password as well.